# Can't encode a file in UTF8/ISO_8859_1

Tags: java

I am trying to write a file to UTF8 or ISO_8859_1 using :

```
BufferedWriter writer = null;
    try {
        writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream(getFile("res")), StandardCharsets.ISO_8859_1));

        String line =" test encoding"+"\r\n";
        writer.write(line);
    } finally {
        try {
            if (writer != null)
                writer.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
    }
```

Then I try to display the file encoding using : file -I, file --mime-encoding but it always shows me us-ascii.

```
file --mime-encoding res
res: us-ascii


file -I res
res: text/plain; charset=us-ascii
```

What am i doing wrong ?

edit1 : I am testing on macos dunno if it changes something

Comment: `file` command finds the encoding based on the file content. Since all the file content is ascii (english), output is ascii. Provide the text in non English characters like [`Greek`](https://translate.google.co.in/?hl=en&sl=en&tl=el&text=test%20encoding&op=translate) and check.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ISO-8859-1 and UTF-8 are both character encodings *designed* to be compatible with older US-ASCII, for all the standard printable characters, meaning codes 0x20 to 0x7E. These characters include all lower and upper case latin letters with no accent, numeric digits, space and other usual punctuation marks.

When you simply write a file using Java, and any other tool (except for some specific character encodings), there is nothing within the file that indicates how it has been encoded.

The tool you're using with the `file` command simply tries to take a guess based on the first bytes of the file: it checks if the sequence makes any sense with a predetermined set of character encodings, reports it when it finds one that seems to match.

In your test, you're only using those standard "english" characters, so any encoding compatible with ascii is suitable for reading the file. That's why you get `us-ascii` as a result.

You'll get a different result if you start using different characters, such as `[éÀÖî]`.

UTF-8, UTF-16 and UTF-32 allow to start the file with a special sequence of bytes called the [**byte-order mark** (BOM)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark), that identifies the file's encoding. You would have to write it yourself before anything else. for UTF-8, the sequence is `0xEFBBBF`

That would be:

```java
try (OutputStream os = Files.newOutputStream(Paths.get("res"), StandardOpenOption.WRITE, StandardOpenOption.TRUNCATE_EXISTING)) {
  os.write(0xEF);
  os.write(0xBB);
  os.write(0xBF);
  try (BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(os, StandardCharsets.UTF_8))) {
    bw.write("Testing with standard us-ascii chars!");
    bw.write(System.lineSeparator());
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am currently debugging this problem and I want to create an Ansi coded txt file, so I just solved this problem by using the following code snippet:

```
Charset charSet1 = StandardCharsets.ISO_8859_1;
BufferedWriter bw1 = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(fos, charSet1));
bw1.write(0xE1);
bw1.newLine();
```

You can use this method but if you can achieve it without printing `0xE1`(which notifies that this code is in Ansi format encoding) pls let the community know.

Thank you.